# Run shortcode before add_filter();

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, add-filter

So I have the shortcode [my_example_shortcode] on my WordPress site.

`add_shortcode( 'my_example_shortcode', 'shortcode_for_project' );`

I want to prioritise the shortcode before
`add_filter('the_content', 'my_example');`

If the shortcode is not found on the page then I want the the code above to be applied.

I have already tried:

```
if (shortcode_for_project) {
  echo do_shortcode('[my_example_shortcode]');
}
else
{
add_filter('the_content', 'my_example');
}
```

---

Let's say I have a page:

> **Business Intelligence**
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sem
> magna, maximus eget odio vel, dictum ultrices nunc.

Then I want
`add_filter('the_content', 'my_example');`
to be **enabled**

But if

> **Business Intelligence**
>
> [my_example_shortcode]
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sem
> magna, maximus eget odio vel, dictum ultrices nunc.

Then I want
`add_filter('the_content', 'my_example');`
to be **disabled**

Comment: `the_title` seems to be executed before `the_content`, could you try `add_filter('the_title', 'my_example');`

Comment: Thanks for your respond, @GrafiCode!
It not work either. :/ I have no clue. At the moment I just do  
`
// add_filter('the_content', 'my_example'); 
`
 When I want to use the shortcode...

Comment: are you wanting to output the result of the shortcode before the output of the_content?

Comment: @mikerojas the shortcode contains a script that needs to run before the content is engraved. `add_filter('the_content', 'my_example');` contains the same script but suppose to run automatically **at the end of the content** if shortcode is **not found**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem here is one way you can do this:

```php
// functions.php

add_filter("the_content", function($content) {
    if (shortcode_exists('my_example_shortcode')) {
        ob_start();
        
        echo do_shortcode('[my_example_shortcode]');

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    return my_example($content);
});
```

Comment: Nope! Sorry, it didn't work.  See the edit to the question.

Comment: @PontusEriksson Updated my answer based on you recent feedback.  let me know if  this is headed in the right direction.

Comment: It now work within the content, thank you @mikerojas. Now the next issue is that I am using this plugin:
[Smart Sidebars Slider](https://demo.smartplugins.info/plugin/smart-sidebars-slider/) and my shortcode `[my_example_shortcode]`. is placed inside that sidebar slider. If you inspect the sidebar widget you find that it's listed very, very low down in the source code. What would you suggest in this case?